# LINQ - How to group and count distinct values?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to do some grouping and aggregation on lists. I need to figure out a way of aggregating the number of instances of a particular value in the output collection. For example...

I'll start with a collection of cars

```
    Private Class Car
        Property Colour As String
        Property Make As String
        Property Doors As Integer
    End Class

    Dim cars = New List(Of Car) _
                From {New Car With {.Colour = "Blue", .Make = "Ford", .Doors = 5},
                        New Car With {.Colour = "Red", .Make = "Ford", .Doors = 2},
                        New Car With {.Colour = "Red", .Make = "Pontiac", .Doors = 3},
                        New Car With {.Colour = "Green", .Make = "Nissan", .Doors = 3},
                        New Car With {.Colour = "Blue", .Make = "Ford", .Doors = 5},
                        New Car With {.Colour = "Blue", .Make = "Pontiac", .Doors = 4},
                        New Car With {.Colour = "Green", .Make = "Nissan", .Doors = 5},
                        New Car With {.Colour = "Blue", .Make = "Volkswagen", .Doors = 5},
                        New Car With {.Colour = "Green", .Make = "Pontiac", .Doors = 3},
                        New Car With {.Colour = "Blue", .Make = "Nissan", .Doors = 2},
                        New Car With {.Colour = "Red", .Make = "Volkswagen", .Doors = 5},
                        New Car With {.Colour = "Red", .Make = "Ford", .Doors = 5}}
```

Then we can write a linq query...

```
    Dim groupedList = (From c In cars
                        Group By c.Make Into Group
                        Select New With {.Make = Make,
                                        .Cars = Group.Count(),
                                        .TotalDoors = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.Doors)}).ToList()
```

This will give us the following results:

- **Make** Ford **Cars** 4 **TotalDoors** 17
- **Make** Pontiac **Cars** 3 **TotalDoors** 10
- **Make** Nissan **Cars** 3 **TotalDoors** 10
- **Make** VolksWagen **Cars** 2 **TotalDoors** 10

Great Stuff! We now know the total number of doors and the total number of cars offered by each of these fine manufacturers. Next I need to know the number of different colours they do, i'll just do this:

```
    Dim groupedList = (From c In cars
                        Group By c.Make Into Group
                        Select New With {.Make = Make,
                                    .Cars = Group.Count(),
                                    .Colours = Group.Count(Function(x) x.Colour),
                                    .TotalDoors = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.Doors)}).ToList()
```

I would be expecting to see another property on each of my list items called  Colour and the number of different colours that they offer...

- **Make** Ford **Cars** 4 **TotalDoors** 17 **Colours** 1
- **Make** Pontiac **Cars** 3 **TotalDoors** 10 **Colours** 2
- **Make** Nissan **Cars** 3 **TotalDoors** 10 **Colours** 2
- **Make** VolksWagen **Cars** 2 **TotalDoors** 10 **Colours** 2

But I dont, I just get a big old error,

```
Run-time exception (line -1): Conversion from string "Blue" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.
```

I'm not sure what to look for on the internet, I'm pretty sure the answer should be simple.

Here is a .net fiddle to play with:
[.Net Fiddle for this question](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3rzqCW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud group grouped result by colours:

```
 Dim groupedList = (From c In cars
                           Group By c.Make Into Group
                           Select New With {.Make = Make,
                            .Cars = Group.Count(),
                            .Colours = Group.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Colour).Count(),
                            .TotalDoors = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.Doors)}).ToList()
```

Updated [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MAo67H)

Comment: Thats the badger!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use select distinct

```
.Colours = Group.Select(Function(x) x.Colour).Distinct.Count
```